# What do Christianity and Judaism have in common?

Tags: judaism, religious-practice, religious-education, comparative-religion, other-religions

Most Christians relate to Judaism more than to Islam, Hinduism, or Buddhism, or any other religion. So, my question is, what do Christianity and Judaism have in common so as to make them so related to one another? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question is a big one--perhaps too big for this site. But we'll see what some of the others think. Meanwhile, for more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Christianity really grew out of Jewish ideas. Jesus was actually brought up Jewish.

Comment: Related: [How did the Christian movement distinguish itself from Judaism?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/40714/21576)

Comment: @resident_heretic: I suppose that statement might make sense from a certain perspective of gross ignorance. But nobody truly familiar with Christianity, Judaism, or any of the various forms of paganism, would make such a rediculous statement.

Comment: A great question, but far, far too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus Christ is Jewish. Therefore we are connected to the Jewish faith because it is our faith with the addition of the teachings of Christ.

Maybe better stated, the Jewish faith, is the history of Christianity by way of Christ's Jewish lineage. His faith and physical ancestors was Jewish.

Comment: @Korvin that is not a traditional belief at all. In fact I've never heard it before, and don't see why anyone would think it was true.

Comment: @curiousdannii I suppose that's only from a Christian perspective.  The other matter is the nature of the deity, and if one accepts the Triune model, to where was and is become irrelevant completely.

Comment: Well only Christian perspectives are ontopic here, so yes...

Answer (score 2):

What Christianity and Judaism share is a part of salvation history, as presented in the Old Testament.

> [Salvation History](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=salvation%20history%20definition) (in German *Heilsgeschichte*) seeks to understand the
>   personal redemptive activity of God within human history to effect his
>   eternal saving intentions. This approach to history is found in parts
>   of the Old Testament written around the sixth century BC, such as
>   Deutero-Isaiah and some of the Psalms.

What Christians teach (in the main) is that the Bible is a record of salvation history and the relationship between God and Mankind.  Jews and Christians agree that there is one God.

While the question is very broad, that in a nutshell is where common ground can be found.

The significant differences (books have been written) begin where Christians believe in how salvation history continues as presented in the New Testament.  (Among the varied Christian sects the disagreements in detail run rampant).  Those adhering to Judaism disagree, and follow a different understanding of the continuing relationship between God and Mankind since they do not hold Jesus as having been the promised Messsiah.

Per your request for amplification on 'the relationship:' the relationship between God and mankind is established in Genesis and continues on throughout the Old Testament.  It follows the pattern of God and mankind being close, then mankind turning away (the Fall) and then a series of turns towards God and turns away from God, among God's people, as time goes on.   [C.S. Lewis wrote of that pattern in his summary of the Bible.](http://www.believersweb.org/view.cfm?ID=815)  Further examples of the relationship are found in the covenants made with Abraham, Moses, and David.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this relationship between God and Mankind you mention? Also, define salvation. Thanks.

Comment: So essentially salvation means entering paradise, if I understand this well. Thanks.