# What is the basis for the claim that Judaism is a Christian Heresy?

Tags: judaism, heresy

**NOTE: This question is asking about anti-semitic claim, not endorsing it**

By necessity, it must include the quote. The point is not to be anti-semitic, but rather to understand the basis of the anti-semitic notion that Judaism should be understood as a Christian heresy, even though Judaism clearly predates Christianity by at least a millennia**

---

I read the below comment a while back. John Struggnell, the lead researcher for the Dead Sea Scrolls in Israel, said:

> In 1990, Strugnell gave an interview to Ha'aretz in which he said that
>   Judaism was a "horrible religion" which "should not exist". He also
>   said that Judaism was "a Christian heresy, and we deal with our
>   heretics in different ways. You are a phenomenon that we haven't
>   managed to convert — and we should have managed." *([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Strugnell))*

The person above is an expert in history, theology, and archaeology. Someone so high placed to make such a comment.

Is there an historical basis for his comment? If not, what is the root? Are Jews and Christians related in some fashion?  Did today's Judaism start somehow as a Christian heresy?

Comment: You should seriously read about the history of Judaism and the Jewish diaspora. This is most ill-researched question I've seen. -1 for lack of research effort.

Comment: You may be seriously asking but seriously, did you do any research from other sources before you asked this? Like, for example, from the Bible? If the Bible claims Christianity to be the fulfillment of pre-Messiah Judaism, how could Judaism be a Christian heresy?

Comment: It's an interesting thought that would need some serious study to support well. Every convert from Christianity to Judaism that I have met converted because they lost faith in the New Testament as inspired scripture and eventually came to believe that Jesus was not the messiah. So they convert to what was before: Judaism. Judaism today is a little different that what it was in 30AD, so you might take this perspective based on those differences, but then you might also call Islam a Christian heresy too, you just choose to go forward to Mohammed instead of backward to Moses.

Comment: As for questions that this community on this site is interested in, this question holds far too much opinion, and will likely be closed from receiving answers for that reason. If you want to be more specific about the history of Judaism, there is a site for [Judaism](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/) and a site for [History](http://history.stackexchange.com/). History is on-topic here, but it must directly relate to Christianity, so something like Christian interactions with Judaism would be on-topic.

Comment: You can also ask about a specific denomination's perspective on Judaism. Since the Catholic Church kind of owns the word heresy (imo) I'd ask was the Catholic Church thinks about modern Judaism, their salvation, whether they are heretics or something else, etc. For future question asking reference please see the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it relies on a temporal impossibility.  Judaism existed for *centuries*, arguably *millennia*, before Christianity was invented, so to suggest that it is an offshoot of the later development is illogical.

Comment: That's my point Monica - there can't be Judaism when there's no Temple as the religion is completely based around that. After Jesus, no more offerings were made in the temple. I agree with fredsbend about his opinion of Christians converting to Judaism. I'm curious about this tidbit that I found some time ago.. I thought people here would just 'know' these things I guess. Anyhow, here we have some evidence of something that happened enough that it was a problem: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9030-judaizing-heresy-zhidovstvu-yushchaya-yeres

Comment: Judaism did not begin in the temple it began in a Tabernacle (Tent). And it is impossible to separate Judaism from Christianity, since the entire Old Testament points to Jesus Christ.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Actually, as much as it pains me to say it, this is not off-topic as this site is about ('Christian') ***beliefs*** - the beliefs don't necessarily have to be logical, just held be some defineable 'Christian' group.

Comment: @Cackles there was Judaism before the temple and Judaism after.  You're describing, basically, a Sadducee position; they were (note past tense) but one group within Judaism.  *Demonstrably* there can be Judaism without the temple because we've been doing that for 2000 years.  I'm not going to argue theology  on a Christian site; I'm just pointing out errors of historical fact.

Comment: @bruisedreed is there a definable group here?  I see claims from one person who does not appear to argue dispassionately from facts (not with that opening line).  If responding to derogatory claims from one person, denomination unstated, is on-topic here, then carry on -- I thought it wasn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the ramblings of an anti-Semite.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's a dumb reason to close. What was wrong with it being primarily opinion based?

Comment: @MonicaCellio While it is to be hoped that the number of  'Christians' that currently hold these views is statistically insignificant, unfortunately there are actually identifiable groups that teach this sort of rubbish. It's the sort of thing you'd find in the "Christian Identity" movement, and the kind of doctrine used to justify anti-semitic purges during the Middle ages.

Comment: @bruisedreed should that group identification be in the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this blatantly ignores the simple fact that Judaism existed long before Christianity and is therefore temporally impossible.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good question - it might help to cut down 'noise' if it was; on the other hand, it seems the issue will be moot anyway - a mod agrees with your point over mine and I certainly won't be fighting to get the question re-opened.

Comment: I have voted to re-open, but I might suggest a further improvement. Perhaps you should ask "What did Strugnell mean by saying that Judaism is a Christian heresy?" This may shed light on the question as worded as well, and also provide insightful guidance when asking followup questions, without asking for subjective interpretation of history.

Comment: I mark the question up and I am not completely happy with all the comments. The question deserves a good answer. That said, the Dead Sea Scrolls are not anti-Semitic, they are for the elect, with all Israel free to join if they so choose. Anybody studying them will get the idea that modern Judaism evolved from early Christianity who remained true to the idea of the elect. To a large extent this was the case. But modern Catholicism is the result of the Reformation. Does that make Catholicism a protestant heresy?

Answer (score 3):

Strange as it may seem, there are people who hold this view currently, and in fact it was actually the doctrine of the Catholic church in the past (I hasten to add, they would not express their doctrine in those terms currently).

Proponents of such a view assume (without sufficient evidence imho) two things:

1. Christians are ***the*** covenant people of God - the true inheritors of the Old Testament religion that was necessarily 'perfected' with the advent of Christ. This doctrine is known as [Supersessionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersessionism) or Replacement Theology and was more widely held in the past than Dual-covenant theologies or Dispensationalism. [This essay on the differences between Israel and the Church](http://www.levitt.com/essays/israel-church) introduces some of the relevant issues.
2. Modern Judaism, is not merely a failure to follow the 'perfected' version of the religion of the Old Testament, but a **departure** from the original. This latter case is built on an association with the Pharisaism that Jesus opposed and modern Judaism, and argues that even further divergence has ensued since. Such arguments point to the destruction of the temple as marking a significant discontinuity in terms of orthopraxis, and highlight things like '[the council of Jamnia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Jamnia)' and the collation of the Talmud as being significant further divergences from the will of God.

Comment: FYI, The Council of Jamnia is a highly discredited idea nowadays.  Very little evidence that it ever existed

Comment: @AffableGeek Thanks for making that point explicitly - the scare quotes I used had that very point in mind and perhaps I should have just come out and said it. The fact is that holders of the view do claim that it was a real event and that it was significant.

Comment: The question has changed. You might want to edit your answer. There's also two reopen votes.

Comment: Well in that case AffableGreek, I guess we can discredit the the exile from Egypt, Moses speaking to God, the red sea parting, and pretty much the majority of the OT since we have no clue where any of that came from. I mean.. those can easily be discredited and have been by many archaeologists and researchers.

Answer (score 2):

In fairness, it is probably best understood in the opposite direction.  Technically, "the Way" - those Jewish followers of Jesus the Christ, were Jewish heretics.

The story is better explained here:
[At what point did Judaism and Christianity diverge?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15267/1039)

For the continuing saga, you may find this useful: [Was Catholicism the first denomination?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/20552/1039)

It should be understood that despite the historical link, non-Jewish Gentiles came to predominate fairly early, explaining the 'millions upon millions with no DNA links.' Most of the New Testament, for example, was written to Gentiles in what is today the country of Turkey.

The Anti-Semitic sentiment that he evinces, however, unfortunately has a fairly lengthy pedigree, as [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/9447/1039) shows.